# Is it necessary to add whole jquery file

Tags: jquery

I have a webpage which is not be online. And I have used few function of jquery. And for that I have to add whole Jquery code to my page because I am not using CDN.

Is there any way so that I don't need whole jQuery code to append in my file?

Comment: yeah you can but shouldn't and it's only in few KB'S so devote your time on other imp. stuffs ,

Comment: Yes I know its only 94 KB but when I append to my file it shows very much contents

Answer (score 4):

> Is it necessary to add whole jQuery file

Yes, it is. Of course, you may remove some parts of it, and create a "limited" version of it for your purposes, but it won't give almost any improvements, while bringing many problems.

> so that I dont need whole jQuery code to append in my file

You don't need to append it. Download a jQuery file ([Download from Google CDN](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js)), place it in the same folder as your HTML or create a subfolder for it, and reference it using

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src='jQuery-2.1.4.min.js'></script>`
  </head>
</html>
```

> Now I don't want any kind of dependency. I need all in a single file

There is no other way to include jQuery functionality without referencing CDN, referencing external file or adding it as an inline script. At the same time, jQuery is an integral library, and you cannot remove something from it (or you can remove not that much).

By the way, minified version of jQuery ([Download from Google CDN](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js)) is a single-line. So, you can do something like this, so that it doesn't bother you:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- jQuery: --> <script>!function(a,b){"object"==typeof module&&"object"==typeof module.exports?module.exports=a.document?b(a,!0):function(a){if(!a.document)throw new Error("jQuery requires a window with a document");return b(a)}:b(a)}("undefined"!=typeof window?window:this,function(a,b){var c=[],d=c.slice,e=c.concat,f=c.push,g=c.indexOf,h={},i=h.toString,j=h.hasOwnProperty,k={},l=a.document,m="2.1.4",n=function(a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)},o=/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g,p=/^-ms-/,q=/-([\da-z])/gi,r=function(a,b){return b.toUpperCase()};n.fn=n.prototype={jquery:m,constructor:n,selector:"",length:0,toArray:function(){return d.call(this)},get:function(a){return null!=a?0>a?this[a+this.length]:this[a]:d.call(this)},pushStack:function(a){var b=n.merge(this.constructor(),a);return b.prevObject=this,b.context=this.context,b},each:function(a,b){return n.each(this,a,b)},map:function(a){return this.pushStack(n.map(this,function(b,c){return a.call(b,c,b)}))},slice:function(){return this.pushStack(d.apply(this,arguments))},first:function(){return this.eq(0)},last:function(){return this.eq(-1)},eq:function(a){var b=this.length,c=+a+(0>a?b:0);return this.pushStack(c>=0&&b>c?[this[c]]:[])},end:function(){return this.prevObject||this.constructor(null)},push:f,sort:c.sort,splice:c.splice},n.extend=n.fn.extend=function(){var a,b,c,d,e,f,g=arguments[0]||{},h=1,i=arguments.length,j=!1;for("boolean"==typeof g&&(j=g,g=arguments[h]||{},h++),"object"==typeof g||n.isFunction(g)||(g={}),h===i&&(g=this,h--);i>h;h++)if(null!=(a=arguments[h]))for(b in a)c=g[b],d=a[b],g!==d&&(j&&d&&(n.isPlainObject(d)||(e=n.isArray(d)))?(e?(e=!1,f=c&&n.isArray(c)?c:[]):f=c&&n.isPlainObject(c)?c:{},g[b]=n.extend(j,f,d)):void 0!==d&&(g[b]=d));return g},n.extend({expando:"jQuery"+(m+Math.random()).replace(/\D/g,""),isReady:!0,error:function(a){throw new Error(a)},noop:function(){},isFunction:function(a){return"function"===n.type(a)},isArray:Array.isArray,isWindow:function(a){return null!=a&&a===a.window},isNumeric:function(a){return!n.isArray(a)&&a-parseFloat(a)+1>=0},isPlainObject:function(a){return"object"!==n.type(a)||a.nodeType||n.isWindow(a)?!1:a.constructor&&!j.call(a.constructor.prototype,"isPrototypeOf")?!1:!0},isEmptyObject:function(a){var b;for(b in a)return!1;return!0},type:function(a){return null==a?a+"":"object"==typeof a||"function"==typeof a?h[i.call(a)]||"object":typeof a},globalEval:function(a){var b,c=eval;a=n.trim(a),a&&(1===a.indexOf("use strict")?(b=l.createElement("script"),b.text=a,l.head.appendChild(b).parentNode.removeChild(b)):c(a))},camelCase:function(a){return a.replace(p,"ms-").replace(q,r)},nodeName:function(a,b){return a.nodeName&&a.nodeName.toLowerCase()===b.toLowerCase()},each:function(a,b,c){var d,e=0,f=a.length,g=s(a);if(c){if(g){for(;f>e;e++)if(d=b.apply(a[e],c),d===!1)break}else for(e in a)if(d=b.apply(a[e],c),d===!1)break}else if(g){for(;f>e;e++)if(d=b.call(a[e],e,a[e]),d===!1)break}else for(e in a)if(d=b.call(a[e],e,a[e]),d===!1)break;return a},trim:function(a){return null==a?"":(a+"").replace(o,"")},makeArray:function(a,b){var c=b||[];return null!=a&&(s(Object(a))?n.merge(c,"string"==typeof a?[a]:a):f.call(c,a)),c},inArray:function(a,b,c){ret /* etc... */</script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: No I dont want any kind of dependency. I need all in a single file

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. The sizzle selector can largely be replaced by `$$` and depending on the browsers you're trying to target many more may be availably without polyfills too.

Check out [you might not need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) for some examples of replicating common functions.